# Access denied when using GmailApp.sendEmail - Missing access token for authorization

Tags: google-apps-script

Despite I have add in my manifest following oauthscopes, I still get the following error when launching the GmailApp.sendEmail method :

```
Access denied:: Missing access token for authorization. Request: MailboxService.SendMessage
```

My manifest looks like this :

```
"oauthScopes": [
"https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.readonly",
"https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets.currentonly",
"https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email",
"https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.send",
"https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.compose",
"https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.addons.current.action.compose",
"https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.send_mail",
"https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets",
"https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.modify"  ],
```

Here is the code :

```
function main_Capitations() {
  var cell_col_number = "";
  var cell_row_number = "";
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('2019-2020');
  //ss.setActiveSelection('A3');
  ss.getRange('A3').activate();

  // Get active cell and get value of it
  var cell = ss.getCurrentCell();
  var cellValue = cell.getValue();

  // Start the loop
  while (cellValue != ""){
    cellValue = cell.getValue();
    if (cellValue != "") {
      //Browser.msgBox("Row: " + cell.getRow() + " Column: " + cell.getColumn() + "Valeur : " + cellValue);

    var infos_user = {};
    infos_user.prenom = sheet.getRange(cell.getRow(),cell.getColumn()+2).getValue();
    infos_user.mail = sheet.getRange(cell.getRow(),cell.getColumn()+3).getValue();
    infos_user.solde_a_payer = sheet.getRange(cell.getRow(),cell.getColumn()+8).getValue();

    Logger.log('infos_user.prenom: ' + infos_user.prenom);
      Logger.log('infos_user.mail: ' + infos_user.mail);
      Logger.log('infos_user.solde_a_payer: ' + infos_user.solde_a_payer);

    if (sheet.getRange(cell.getRow(),cell.getColumn()+9).isChecked()  == false) {
      sendmail_paiement(infos_user);  
    }
    };
    cell = cell.offset(1, 0);
    Logger.log('infos_user.mail: ' + cell.getValue());
  };  

  var infos_globales = {};
  infos_globales.solde_global = sheet.getRange(cell.getRow()-1,cell.getColumn()+8).getValue();
  infos_globales.nb_frere_hospitalier = sheet.getRange(cell.getRow()-1,cell.getColumn()+9).getValue();
  infos_globales.nb_frere_retard =sheet.getRange(cell.getRow()-1,cell.getColumn()+10).getValue();

  Logger.log('infos_globales.solde_global ' + infos_globales.solde_global);
  Logger.log('infos_globales.nb_frere_hospitalier ' + infos_globales.nb_frere_hospitalier);
  Logger.log('infos_globales.nb_frere_retard  ' + infos_globales.nb_frere_retard );

  sendmail_synopsis(infos_globales);  
}

function sendmail_paiement(infos_user) {

   var templ = HtmlService
  //.createTemplateFromFile('tpl_mail_traditionnel');
   .createTemplateFromFile('tpl_test');
  //.createTemplateFromFile('tpl_mail_exceptionnel');


  templ.infos_user = infos_user;

  var message = templ.evaluate().getContent();

  //Browser.msgBox(infos_user.mail);

  if (infos_user.solde_a_payer>0) {
    GmailApp.sendEmail(
      infos_user.mail,
      "Rappel de capitations", 
      '', 
      {htmlBody: message,}
    );
  }
}

function sendmail_synopsis(infos_globales) {
  var templ = HtmlService
   .createTemplateFromFile('mail_synopsis_template');

  templ.infos_globales = infos_globales;

  var message = templ.evaluate().getContent();

  GmailApp.sendEmail(
    'zzzxxxyyy@gmail.com',
    "Résumé de la trésorerie du Gaïac", 
    '', 
    {htmlBody: message,}
  );

}
```

It looks like some other people had the same error than me, but they could solve it (not me) with the following line in manifest :

> "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.send_mail",

What did I miss??

Thanks for help !

Comment: Can you paste your code snippet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using two different email sending scopes:

- "...//www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.send"
- "...//www.googleapis.com/auth/script.send_mail"

The scope:

"...//www.googleapis.com/auth/script.send_mail"

is only for the MailApp class.  You are using the GmailApp class.

You should not use both email sending scopes.  The MailApp class is more restricted in it's access to the user's data.  All it can do is send an email.

If the error goes away by changing from GmailApp to MailApp, then I'm guessing that there is some kind of conflict with those two scopes.

Comment: Hello Alan thanks for answering.
I did rewrited the code following your advice. Thanks for this.
It's logging only the first line and then when calling GmailApp.sendEmail same error.

Comment: What do you mean? GmailApp.sendEmail? it's a method to send email via Google Apps Scripts and I think it comes from Gmail yes

Comment: I change GmailApp to MailApp and it's working thanks for your help Alan !

Comment: Thanks for letting me know what worked.  I'm guessing that there is some kind of conflict between the two email sending scopes.

Comment: Yes I just changed from GmailApp to MailApp and everything suddenly worked fine :)